# JSF not updating changes in CSS

Tags: css, eclipse, jsf-2, glassfish

i have a JSF-Project and i wanted to style my xhtml pages.
i included my css using:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="master.css" library="css" />
</h:head>
```

my css is located under WebContent/resources/css/master.css and its
actually just this:

```
#page{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

#content{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    margin-right:16px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

when i change the height for example at the content section to 600px
really nothing changes after starting my glassfish and deploying my
project. i restartet eclipse and i even restarted my computer
after i changed my css. when i delete my css all styles are gone, so
it is correctly rendered. when i reinclude my css he still just shows 
300px insead of my 600px.

Whats wrong there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refresh browser cache  - Ctrl + F5